# Javascript: How to switch div content?

Tags: javascript, html, switch-statement, hidden

Using an onclick function, I'm trying to take the content from a hidden div, and place it into a visible div. Instead of the content showing up, I get [object HTMLDivElement] instead. How do I fix that?

My code:

```
function infoclick1(){
    var x = document.getElementById('HIDE1');
    document.getElementById('moreinfo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('moreinfo').innerHTML = x.innerHTML; ??

Comment: You are assigning the `div` element returned by `document.getElementById` to `x` rather than the div's content. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
function infoclick1(){
    var x = document.getElementById('HIDE1').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('moreinfo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WK8sW/

Answer (score 1):

You want to set it to x's innerHTML, so

```
document.getElementById('moreinfo').innerHTML = x.innerHTML;
```